# Suppose $b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|b| < \frac{1}{n}$ for every positive integer n. Prove that $b = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

This comes from an exercise in Appendix C from Axler's [Measure, Integration & Real Analysis](http://measure.axler.net). The following is my approach.

Suppose $b \neq 0$. Let $|b| = \epsilon$. Then 
        by Archimedean Property (2) 
        $$\exists n^* \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \text{ such that} \frac{1}{n^*} < \epsilon$$
        but $b < \frac{1}{n}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Hence a contradiction.

Am I approaching this correctly, if I am are there any other approaches?

Comment: I don't understand what's that “(2)” doing in your question. The rest is correct.

Comment: It is cleaner is you use contraposition instead of contradiction. Contraposition for your statement is, for all b!=0 there exists an n such that |b|>=1/n.

Answer (score 2):

You are approaching it correctly and your approach is the simplest and intuitive way.

But if you wish to be direct and analytical you could do the following.

$b\in \mathbb R$ so there exist a sequence of $q_n \in \mathbb Q$ so that $q_n \to b$.

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exist an $N$ so that $n > N$ implies $|q_n - b| < \frac {\epsilon}2$.  But there is also a $k\in \mathbb N$ so that $0 < \frac 1k < \frac \epsilon 2$.

So $|q_n- 0| \le |q_n - b| + |b-0|$.  $|q_n - b| < \frac \epsilon 2$ and $|b-0| = |b| < \frac 1k < \frac \epsilon 2$ so $|q_n - 0| < \frac \epsilon 2 + \frac \epsilon 2 = \epsilon$.

So $\lim_{n\to \infty} q_n = 0$.  But $b = \lim_{n\to \infty} q_n $. So $b = 0$.

But... I'd prefer to read *your* proof than *my* proof.

Answer (score 2):

## Proof

Assume that $a \neq 0.$ Then $|a| \neq 0.$ Take $N=\lfloor\dfrac{1}{|a|}\rfloor+1 \in \mathbb{Z_+},$ where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the floor integer function. Then $$\frac{1}{|a|}<\lfloor\dfrac{1}{|a|}\rfloor+1=N,$$ which implies that $$|a|>\frac{1}{N},$$which contradicts.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct. There are several ways to define $\Bbb R$ from $\Bbb Q.$ They all result in isomorphic structures... Up to isomorphism there is only one ordered field in which every non-empty subset with a lower bound has a greatest lower  bound, which is why we say "the" real number system, not "a" real number system.

Suppose we only have $\Bbb Q$ and we hope to have an ordered field $F$ with the $glb$ property.  Then there cannot exist $b\in F$ such that $0\ne b$ and $|b|\leq 1/n$ for every $n\in \Bbb N.$

Proof: Suppose not. (i).  Consider the set $S=\{|b|/n:n\in \Bbb N\}.$ Then $|b|^2$ is a positive lower bound for $S$ because for every $n\in \Bbb N$ we have $|b|^2=|b|\cdot |b|\leq |b|\cdot (1/n).$

(ii). But $S$ has no $glb.$ Because if $c>0$ and $c$ is a lower bound for $S,$ then $c<2c.$ And for every $n$ $\in \Bbb N$ we have $c\leq |b|/2n,$ implying $2c\leq |b|/n.$ So $2c$ is also a lower bound for $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Υou are right . I cannot find any problem in your nice method,  but you forgot the absolute value of $b$.

One another approach would be considering $b$ as a sequence...then $lim{1/n}=0$ so by contraction lemma we should also have $limb=0$ which leads of course to $b=0$

Comment: @amWhy Maybe dmtri did answer the question after all.  He is the only one so far to identify that the OP forgot to use absolute value in the last line (i.e., it should be $|b|<\dfrac1n$, and not $b<\dfrac1n$).  I myself didn't realize that until I saw dmtri's answer.   So, dmtri did anser this question "Am I approaching this correctly" by the OP.

Comment: @amWhy, sorry I elaborated a bit my answer now